# How do you open an XML file and append data to it?

Tags: c#, xml

What is the best way to open an existing xml file and append a section to it?

Here is my non-working code:

```
XDocument usersDoc = XDocument.Load(@"Users.xml");

XElement userInfo =
new XElement("Users",
    new XElement("User",
    new XElement("ScreenName", ScreenNameTB.Text),
    new XElement("Key", KeyTB.Text),              
    new XElement("UserID", UserIdTB.Text)));
usersDoc.Add(userInfo);
usersDoc.Save(@"Users.xml");
```

I believe my error (if I'm on the right path) is in the usersDoc.Add(userInfo) line. But I may be off base entirely.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If possible, you might want to consider creating a class which serializes/deserializes to the given XML. You could then do your adding in code and serialize it to XML when you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the XmlDocument.CreateElement to do it like that.

Serialisation or XmlWriter would be a lot less code, and you wouldn't have to load the entire document into memory to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using XmlWriter following an example from [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter).